# JavaFX UI has broken after installing jdk 8 using eclipse(Kepler)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using jdk7u45 -64 bit in eclipse kepler for developing javafx project.currently i installed jdk 8 as well as setting up the path for jdk 8.But i faced problem such as after running javafax project the ui got broken? Broken in a sense that the position of components,size , alignment got changed.By the way, I handled those using css. How can I solved that?

Comment: Which JDK are you actually using to run projects (look in Preferences / Java / Installed JREs)?

Comment: jdk 1.8.0.Do i need to add any thing else

Comment: JDK 1.8 is still early access so you have to expect problems. If you switch back to 1.7 I expect things will work.

Comment: yes i have already switch back.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem after update from Java 7 to Java 8 and Netbeans 7.4 to 8. Nervously rolled everything back as the Project in Java 8 started with different design, loss functionality and errors. Rolling back to Netbeans 7.4 and Java 7 broke JavaFx classpaths in Netbeans. I did the following to solve:

1. Created start-up JavaFX Application.
2. Project Properties - Libraries - Compile - Add jar/folder:

   - /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/deploy.jar
   - /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/javaws.jar
   - /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar
   - /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/plugin.jar

Decided to migrate during a less busy period.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Netbeans 7.4. It supports JDK 8.